# Add suffix to dataframe column without changing the structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a suffix to a few columns of the pandas dataframe without touching the existing columns. I tried with the below code but it removes all the other columns:

```
df_client.iloc[:,-3:].add_suffix('_P1')
```

I can break the dataframe in two, rename columns of the 2nd dataframe and merge them back, but I wanted to know if there is an easier option available in pandas.

Sample input:
df:

```
Name DL PL KH DL PL KH 
A     1  1  2  3  4  1
B     1  1  2  3  4  1
```

Expected output:
df:

```
Name DL PL KH DL_P1 PL_P1 KH_P1 
A     1  1  2    3    4     1
B     1  1  2    3    4     1
```

Comment: pandas DF doesn't allow duplicate column names. Shouldn't the second set of DL, PL, KH column already have a suffix once you create the DF? I tried and it was ".1" for all. May be I'm missing something

Comment: When you read dataframe from a file which has same column names, it is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `df.columns` it outputs a collection of strings. These are the column names.

If you have a list of column names you want to change to, let's say it's called `new_list`, you can do `df.columns = new_list`. This changes the names of all the columns, without changing data. (Gotta make sure the lists are the same length)

So just prepare a list of new column names.

```
new_columns = list(df.columns[:-3]) + [c + "_P1" for c in df.columns[-3:]]
```

Then simply `df.columns = new_columns`.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't a builtin function, you can use a custom function:

```
def suffix():
    yield ''
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield f'_P{i}'

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(suffix)

df.columns  = df.columns.map(lambda x: x+next(d[x]))
```

output:

```
  Name  DL  PL  KH  DL_P1  PL_P1  KH_P1
0    A   1   1   2      3      4      1
1    B   1   1   2      3      4      1
```